# Can I add a class to a div, when hovering over another class, without using jQuery in Ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ember.js

I have created a table in Ember, and when I hover over the specific header cell for a column, I want to highlight the entire column.

I accomplished this quite easily, but I'm told that this may not be "the ember way".

New to ember, so I'm double checking.

***HTML***

- onmouseover I call highlightBlocks I send the ID of the header cell
- onmouseout I call unhighlightBlocks (removes class, not adding it
  because)

*Ember component*

```
highlightBlocks(value) {
 this.$(`.${value}`).addClass('highlighted-block');
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?
What's the ember way?

Comment: Can you please share a working Ember Twiddle ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the "Ember way", what you'd do is use an action that sets a property on mouseEnter and mouseLeave that the individual rows & columns check.

```
<th 
    {{action 'setHover' 'colId1' on="mouseEnter"}} 
    {{action 'removeHover' 'colId1' on="mouseLeave"}}>
    Column 1 Header</th>

<th 
    {{action 'setHover' 'colId2' on="mouseEnter"}} 
    {{action 'removeHover' 'colId2' on="mouseLeave"}}>
    Column 2 Header</th>

<th 
    {{action 'setHover' 'colId3' on="mouseEnter"}} 
    {{action 'removeHover' 'colId3' on="mouseLeave"}}>
    Column 3 Header</th>
```

`setHover` will set a property called "hoveredCol" to the column Id.

```
setHover(colId){
    this.set('hoveredCol',colId);
}
```

`removeHover` will reset the hovered column.

```
removeHover(colId){
    if (this.get('hoveredCol) === colId) {
        this.set('hoveredCol',null);
    }
}
```

In the template,  you add a class to the cells if its hovered.

```
<tr>
    <td {{if (eq hoveredCol 'colId1') 'hover'}}>Data 1</td>
    <td {{if (eq hoveredCol 'colId2') 'hover'}}>Data 2</td>
    <td {{if (eq hoveredCol 'colId3') 'hover'}}>Data 3</td>
</tr>
```

Now, when the column header is hovered, the row gets the class that marks it as hovered.

A rough example (that works slightly differently) can be seen in [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8a7ba2f9e1427cb7cee60ee44644c677?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C).

Comment: This is exactly what I did.  I started writing my explanation, walked away, then saw this.  Your answer is better than I was writing.

So thanks! for this.

Answer (score 1):

depending on your version of ember, you should `this.element`.
the rest is vanilla javascript :)

so, you could do something like:

```
this.element.classList.add('highlighted-block');
```

if you want a sub-element, you can do

```
this.element
  .querySelector(someSelector)
  .classList.add('highlighted-block');
```

Comment: This was great, but not exactly what I was looking for.  Coming from a non-web background, this was a useful thing, so thanks for the answer.

I'm adding my solution to my original question.